# C++ STL vector.erase() always deletes last element

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

Using: Eclipse 3.8.1, C/C++ Remote Debug Launcher 6.0.0, with GCC 1.1.0, and GDB 7.0.0
Verified on: Visual Studio 2010

I am pulling my hair out on this one.  When using the following code, the last element of the vector of Room objects *rooms* is always removed.  I cannot get any element other than the last to erase with this code.  I am only trying to remove one element (the location is determined by the user).

I know that many of you are probably asking why I don't use a list, but random data access is much more important than ease of element addition / removal with this collection.  Do you have any ideas?

```
void House::removeRoom(unsigned int roomToRemove){
    try{
        if(roomDoesNotExist(roomToRemove)) throw houseException("Room requested to     remove does not exist", roomToRemove, __FILE__, __LINE__);

        vector<Room>::iterator roomIterator = rooms.begin() + roomToRemove;
        rooms.erase(roomIterator);

        removeAllLinksToRoom(roomToRemove);
        renumberLinkedRoomsAfterErase(roomToRemove);
    }
    catch(houseException& hException){
        hException.display(cerr);
    }
}
```

Here is a snippet of the House class:

```
#include "Room.h"

using namespace std;

class House {
public:
    vector<Room> rooms;

    //member functions
    void removeRoom(unsigned int roomToRemove);


    //constuctors / destructors
    House();
    virtual ~House();

    //STL linked list overload operators =, ==, and <
    House &operator=(const House &rhs);
    int operator==(const House &rhs) const;
    int operator<(const House &rhs) const;

private:
    bool roomDoesNotExist(int roomToRemove);
    void removeAllLinksToRoom(int roomToUnlink);
    void renumberLinkedRoomsAfterErase(int erasedRoom);
};
```

Because it could be relevant, I included my entire Room class:

```
#include "Wall.h"

#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

#include "exceptions/houseException.h"

using namespace std;

class Room {
    public:
    float setPointDegF;
    vector<Wall> walls;  //TODO consider making walls protected / private

    private:
    string roomName;
    vector<int> linkedRooms;
    float storedTemperature;
    float storedHumidity;

    //member functions
    void linkToRoom(int roomToLink);
    void unlinkFromRoom(int roomToUnlink);

    void removeAllLinksToRoom(int roomToUnlink);
    void renumberLinkedRoomsAfterErase(int erasedRoom);

public:
    //friends
    friend class House;

    //member functions
    void addWalls(unsigned int numWallsToAdd=1);
    void removeWall(unsigned int wallToRemove);

    //Sensor Functions
    void readSensorTemperature();
    void readSensorHumidity();

    void temperature();
    void humidity();

    //constuctors / destructors
    Room();
    virtual ~Room();
//STL linked list overload operators =, ==, and <
    Room &operator=(const Room &rhs);
    int operator==(const Room &rhs) const;
    int operator<(const Room &rhs) const;
private:
    void getAttachedRooms(Wall& tempWall);

    bool wallDoesNotExist(unsigned int wallToRemove);
    bool roomLinked(int roomToLink);
    bool roomNotLinked(int roomToLink);

    vector<int>::iterator findRoom(int roomToFind);
    vector<int>::iterator findInsertionPoint(int roomToInsert);


};
```

Comment: What does your vector contain and what is the index passed?

Comment: *"I know that many of you are probably asking why I don't use a list"* -- No we're not.  The uses for linked lists are few and far between, and they are way over-emphasized in CS courses.

Comment: It's hard to answer because so much code is missing.  You do realize though that `rooms.erase(roomIterator);` will shift all the elements after roomToRemove to the left.  So if roomToRemove is 4, whatever was at rooms[5] is now at room[4].

Comment: I take it from the name of the function you're supposed to be removing a *single* room from your vector. not sure why you're renumbering afterward, but provided your room number being removed is between 0 and (rooms.size()-1), this should work.

Comment: "with this code" --- which code? No code that erases something is shown.

Comment: @n.m. The sixth line in the first snippet : `rooms.erase(roomIterator);` seems pretty clear to me, at least in its intent. But you're correct. Some actual *usage* of this class in a SSCCE would certainly go a long way in exhibiting the OP's issue.

Comment: @WhozCraig: indeed, I must have gone blind temporarily.

Comment: @n.m. pfft. not a day goes by I don't suffer from that affliction to some degree.

Comment: Setting aside the question of what `roomToRemove` actually means after calling `erase`, how do you know which one of the vector elements was erased?  Have you looked at the vector with a debugger right after tat call?

Comment: My renumbering function name may be unclear.  Each room keeps track of which rooms it is attached to physically.  If I erase an element, all of these lists are obsoleted for rooms with a number higher than the erased room.

Comment: @neghzero well the 3 private methods would be a beginning.  It's hard to know what you're checking for example.  If instead of the if with `roomDoesNotExit`, you had `if (roomToRemove >= rooms.size() { throw Blah; }`, that'd be very clear

Comment: Also, does the Room class have an assignment operator and a copy constructor defined correctly?

Comment: Post enough code (and no more) to demonstrate the problem clearly (something we can compile and run, this means a `main` function). Explain what output are getting, and how it differs from your expectations. http://sscce.org/

Comment: @n.m. My assignment and copy constructors may not be defined correctly.  I think you might have found my problem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Sorry man.  This is my first post on Stack Overflow.  I was trying to cut out all extraneous code, but I may have gone too far.  To compile and run my code as-is requires about 20 files to cover the dependencies associated with House.h.  I will try to refine this art as I interact with the community more.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you SO MUCH.  I tried to overload the default assignment operator and failed miserably.  When I commented out that code and used the implicit &= operator, life is good.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n.m. answered this in the comments below my question, but I am retyping it here for clarity:

> Also, does the Room class have an assignment operator and a copy
>   constructor defined correctly? – n.m.

Answer:  No.  An explicit Room class assignment operator was causing the issue.

> I tried to overload the default assignment operator and failed
>   miserably. When I commented out that code and used the implicit &=
>   operator, life is good. Problem solved. -neghzero

Answer (score 1):

`rooms.erase(roomIterator)` will delete the element at location `roomIterator`. If you want to delete all elements from beginning to `roomToRemove`, use `rooms.erase(rooms.begin(), rooms.begin()+roomToRemove)` or `rooms.erase(rooms.begin(), roomIterator)`

Comment: I'm going to suggest the very name of the function is a strong indicator he is trying to remove a *single* room from the list.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, you may be correct. But when I read `I cannot get any element other than the last to erase with this code.` -- I interpreted that he is trying to remove more than one, or at least not only the last element...I may be wrong.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  I am only trying to remove a single element within the vector container.